# Can I use "ideal diode" in series in solar cells?

Tags: diodes, solar-cell, low-power, schottky, mppt

i have a small experimental solar panel system to gain knowledge before moving on large power systems.

My system is 5 solar cells in series, each 5.8V 0,52A (peak power). So total is 29V 0,52A (about 15W). Output is connected to LT8705 MPPT charger.
I have a common problem with shadow of tree moving across the panels during the day so I installed bypass schottky diodes across each panel like this:

[image]

I am using PMEG4050 schottky diode, that draws about 0,35V. Not bad but would like to improve it because in larger PV cells this will be a huge power loss.

Can I use the ideal diode controller with MOSFET (like LM5050) as a plug in replacement of diodes here? The loss should be almost 14x lower with 50 mohm MOSFET. But I am concerned about grounding. I think each ideal diode "unit" should be grounded with common ground (can be tha last PV cell negative?). If i understnad the block schematic of ideal diode right, the mosfet should remain off if power supply of any solar cell drop below 5V and should not cause any problem. Or maybe I can use common bias power from solar output to power up all diodes at once with single supply (29 V).

Or I am wrong? On internet there are only mentions about using ideal diodes in paralel, not in series. Any thoughts about this topic is appreciated!

Comment: Not answering the direct question, but a remark for your intended larger PV system: If you have a lot of shading on your cells you might want to check out *micro inverters* instead of string inverters. This solves the problem of bypassing the shaded cells completly.

Comment: _”draws about 0,35V”_ Diodes don’t draw anything. You mean drop.